# Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

https://github.com/calvertwong/typescript-eslint-error-on-start

I am having issue with @typescript-eslint and I am getting an Failed to compile error when executing `npm start`.

`Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`

I have two React typescript projects and they both use the same configuration but one of them is giving me the error. I have provided a github link above, can someone help me out? I have tried downgrading eslint related version but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

I have resolved this issue. I believe react-script is using babel-eslint which is deprecated and was giving me trouble but I am not too sure about it. What I did was I execute `npm audit fix --force`, saw react-script being upgraded from version 4.3 to 5 and the failed to load plugin issue went away.